# When looping through an array I wish to push the elements to a new array. That array however remains empty

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

When I run this loop it takes in an array which contains eight numbers, it loops through and simply pushes them to a global array which is named results. For some reason when I console.log this array outside of the loop it returns 0 []. I wish it to return the eight numbers from the other array.

```js
const results = []

const validate = arr => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    results.push(arr[i])
  }

}
console.log(results)
```

Comment: You haven't executed the `validate` function anywhere, why do you expect it to work?

Comment: `validate` doesn't seem the right name for this function fwiw.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your code would work if you included the original array of numbers and you call the function that iterates over it:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
let results = [];

function validate() {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    results.push(arr[i])
  }
}

validate();
console.log(results)
```

But, the [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method was designed to do just this type of thing:

```js
let arr = [2,4,6,8];

let results = arr.map(function(element){
  return element; // Returns item to resulting array
});

console.log(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have to run the **function** validate, now you are just printing `results[]` which has no items.

```
validate(arr);
```

```js
const results = []
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const validate = arr => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    results.push(arr[i])
  }

}
validate(arr);
console.log(results);
```

But if you want to make a copy, you can just use:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const results = [...arr];
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have done here is simply define a function that copies the contents of  the array that has been passed into it. You need to call the function
`validate` with the appropriate value.

```js
const results = []

const validate = arr => {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    results.push(arr[i])
  }

}
validate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed calling the function.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
const result = [];
arr.map((num) => result.push(num));
console.log(result);
```

Comment: What does this answer provide that the others don't already provide?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const results = []
const validate = (arr) => {
    console.log(arr)
    arr.forEach((value)=>{
        results.push(value)
    });
}

validate([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
console.log(results);
```